# Number of binary sequences containing a prefix with more 0's than 1's

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Consider the set of all $(o+z)$-sized binary strings that contains $o$ 1's and $z$ zeros (and we assume $o>z$).

Obviously, there are ${o + z \choose z}$ such sequences.

I was wondering how many of them contain a prefix in which there number of zeros which is greater than or equal to the number of ones.

E.g., 10011 is counted, while 11010 is not.
In the case of $o=3, z=2$, the answer should be 8, as we have {$00111,01011,01101,01110,10011,10101,10110,11001$}. The sequences which should not be counted are $11010$ and $11100$.

How can we compute the number of such sequences?

This probably is related to Catalan numbers, but I don't see the direct connection.

Thank you very much !

Comment: why is 10110 counted?

Comment: Because it has the prefix "10", in which there is an equal number of 0's and 1's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a variant of [Bertrand’s ballot problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem). If you give the $\binom{o+z}z$ strings the uniform distribution and pick one at random, Bertrand’s ballot theorem says that the probability that it will *not* have such a prefix is

$$\frac{o-z}{o+z}\;.$$

Thus, the number of sequences *with* such a prefix is

$$\begin{align*}
\left(1-\frac{o-z}{o+z}\right)\binom{o+z}z&=\frac{2z}{o+z}\binom{o+z}z\\
&=2\binom{o+z-1}{z-1}\\
&=2\binom{o+z-1}o\;.
\end{align*}\tag{1}$$

As a partial check, note that if $o=z+1$, the ‘bad’ strings are those that have a $1$ followed by a string of length $2z$ that corresponds to a Dyck path, so there are $C_z$ such strings and therefore

$$\begin{align*}
\binom{o+z}z-C_z&=\binom{2z+1}z-\frac1{z+1}\binom{2z}z\\
&=\binom{2z+1}z-\frac1{2z+1}\binom{2z+1}z\\
&=\frac{2z}{2z+1}\binom{2z+1}z\\
&=2\binom{2z}{z-1}\\
&=2\binom{o+z-1}{z-1}\;,
\end{align*}$$

as given by $(1)$.

Comment: M.Scott Can this be modified to get the number of ways o+z can arranged such that at any prefix number of o is greater than z by some valid fixed value?